# DTD Parsing: Parameter entity reference name including another parameter entity reference - is it well formed?

Tags: xml, escaping, dtd, sgml

I'm writing a DTD parser and I'm a little uncertain how to expand parameter entities. For example is this DTD excerpt valid?

```
<!ENTITY % xx '&#37;zz;'>
<!ENTITY % zz '&#60;!ENTITY tricky "error-prone" >' >
<!ENTITY % abcd '%xx;'>
<!ENTITY % ef 'c'>
<!ENTITY % gh '%ab%ef;d;'>
%gh;
```

More specifically I'm curious to know if entity gh will expand correctly. In my opinion %ef; should expand first to 'c' and then the newly formed PE reference %abcd; should expand to %xx; and so on.

Most of the parsers I've seen are identifying %ab as a PE reference and fail since that PE is not defined. But I found absolutely no reference in the standard asking for the parser to work this way. The only reference I found was [Included in Literal](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#inliteral) as opposed to [Included as PE](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#as-PE) where it states that the replacement text must be enlarged with one leading and one following 0x20 - but not in a literal.

Any pointers?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rows of the example code of this question are taken from [this example](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-entexpand) in the W3C XML recommendation, so those who are not familiar with the quite convoluted logic of the DTD escapes should see the explanation that is written there.

> More specifically I'm curious to know if entity gh will expand
>   correctly.

No, it won't. Reason for this is that your definition for parameter entity `gh` has malformed syntax. Syntax for parameter entity definitions is: ([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-entity-decl))

```
PEDecl   ::=    '<!ENTITY' S '%' S Name S PEDef S? '>'
PEDef    ::=    EntityValue | ExternalID
```

and syntax for entity values is: ([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EntityValue))

```
EntityValue   ::=       '"' ([^%&"] | PEReference | Reference)* '"'
                        |  "'" ([^%&'] | PEReference | Reference)* "'"
```

"PEReference" is a parameter entity reference (`%Name;`) and "Reference" is either a general entity reference (`&Name;`)or a character reference (`&#123;` or `&#x7B`). ([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Reference))

Here `[^%&"]` and `[^%&']` mean that the entity value cannot contain a `%` character unless it denotes the start of a (parameter entity) name production. And because `%` is not a valid name character, but it appears before the name production end character `;`, the character sequence `%ab%` will cause an error. I'd say it should work if the first `%` sign is replaced with a character reference so then the `%ef;` entity replacement is done before the `%ab...` is seen as a reference to a parameter entity name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed answer. Obviously the entity values have their own grammar. Somehow that part completely slipped my mind when I was looking for a solution.